# Calculating Vertex normals weird results

Tags: c++, vectormath

I know this has been asked quiet a few times but my Problem is not about how to do it. I know how this works (or at least I think so ^^) but something seems to be wrong with my implementation and I can't get behind it.
I have a procedurally generated Terrain mesh and I'm trying to calculate the normals for each vertex by averaging the normals of all the triangles this vertex is connected to. When setting the normal xyz to the rgb vertex colors it seems as if it's randomly either black (0, 0, 0) or blue (0, 0, 1).

```
void CalculateVertexNormal(int index){  //index of the vertex in the mesh's vertex array
    std::vector<int> indices;   //indices of triangles the vertex is a part of
    Vector normals = Vector(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    //sum of all the face normals

    for(int i = 0; i < triangles.size(); i += 3){   //iterate over the triangle array in order
        if(triangles[i] == index)                   //to find the triangle indices
            indices.push_back(triangles[i]);
        else if(triangles[i + 1] == index)
            indices.push_back(triangles[i]);
        else if(triangles[i + 2] == index)
            indices.push_back(triangles[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++){    //iterate over the indices to calculate the normal for each tri
        int vertex = indices[i];
        Vector v1 = vertices[vertex + 1].GetLocation() - vertices[vertex].GetLocation();    //p1->p2
        Vector v2 = vertices[vertex + 2].GetLocation() - vertices[vertex].GetLocation();    //p1->p3

        normals += v1.Cross(v2);    //cross product with two edges to receive face normal
    }

    vertices[index].SetNormals(normals.Normalize());    //normalize the sum of face normals and set to vertex
```

}

Maybe somebody could have a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you.

Edit:
Thanks to molbdnilo's comment I finally understood what was wrong. It was a problem with indexing the arrays and my two loops were kind of confusing as well, maybe I should get some rest ;)
I eventually came up with this, reduced to one loop:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < triangles.size(); i += 3){
        if(triangles[i] == index || triangles[i + 1] == index || triangles[i + 2] == index){
            Vector v1 = vertices[triangles[i + 1]].GetLocation() - vertices[index].GetLocation();
            Vector v2 = vertices[triangles[i + 2]].GetLocation() - vertices[index].GetLocation();

            faceNormals += v1.Cross(v2);
        }
    }

    vertices[index].SetNormals(faceNormals.Normalize());
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second loop say `vertices[triangles[vertex + 1]]`, and so on?

Comment: I think what you want is the normal for the triangle.  Since any 2 adjoining triangles are not required (nor desired) to be planar summing the normals of all adjoining triangles is really meaningless.  Imagine 3 triangles forming the peak of a mountain.  Each triangle normal will point in a different direction.  What does summing these normals mean at the peak vertex?

Comment: @Matt No, I'm looking for the vertex normal. You can calculate it using the surrounding face normals.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank You! your answer gave me the idea to the solution :)